# spring @crossorigin not working for the application

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, cors

I'm new to spring. There is an existing spring project(Not maven, its a dynamic web project) on 4.3.9 version which is a working fine. I've written a new @RestController in the project and tried to access this controller from different machine. It throws me the

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://<URL>. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
```

There are only two files available for config here. There are no XML files for configuration. I'm confused where to add the cors filter config for the Application totally. I've added **addCorsMappings** in the AppInitializer Class. But still it doesnt work.

If I add `@CrossOrigin(origins = "*", maxAge = 3600)` it works on a controller only. I want for the total application.

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "*", maxAge = 3600) -> This works only controller lvel
@RestController
public class CTUController {
     // code
}
```

Kindly suggest me where to add

### AppConfig class

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "net.qdj.spring")
public class AppConfig{

}
```

### AppInitializer

```
public class AppInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

@SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes", "unchecked" })
@Override
protected Class[] getRootConfigClasses() {
    return new Class[] { AppConfig.class };
}

@SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes", "unchecked" })
@Override
protected Class[] getServletConfigClasses() {
    return null;
}

@Override
protected String[] getServletMappings() {
    return new String[] { "/" };
}

// Added for CORS -> Not working for application level
public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
    registry.addMapping("/**");
}

}
```

Kindly advice me in this context

Answer (score 0):

Use allowedOrigins.

```
registry.addMapping("/**").allowedOrigins("http://localhost:9000");
```

Instead of :

```
registry.addMapping("/**");
```